# Why is stopping (or restarting) squid3 on GNU/Linux is so slow?

Tags: ubuntu, squid, performance, upstart

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and when calling "/etc/init.d/squid3 restart", it spends about half a minute to restart. What is it doing?

The output looks like this:

```
* Restarting Squid HTTP Proxy 3.x squid3
*  Waiting...
* ...
* ...
* ...
* ...
* ...
* ...                                                                   [ OK ]
* Creating Squid HTTP Proxy 3.x cache structure
```

Answer (score 13):

Lower your `shutdown_lifetime` setting. It's set to 30 seconds by default.

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/shutdown_lifetime/

Answer (score 0):

Because it closes all the file descriptors, sockets before stop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does not apply to you.. since this assumes that squid is broken.

I had a running/working squid on Ubuntu 14 and after 2 upgrades to Ubuntu 18, where the config files and folders happily changed, it would not properly start - but only visible in the log, no error thrown, systemctl also reported it started and stopped successfully.

After fixing the startup problem, a medium-high cpu load is gone, long restart time is gone, and I assume the proxy is working, too.

All I had to do in my case was copy the missing config file (squid_passwd in my case) from old config folder to new config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your **/etc/squid/squid,conf**

```
shutdown_lifetime 0 seconds
```